# How can I move floats that aren't tables or figures to the end of a document (endfloat for listings)?

Tags: floats, listings, endfloat

I use [`endfloat`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/endfloat/) to move all figures and tables to the end of my document.
I want to apply the same to other floats that I have in my document, for example `listing` environments.

Is there some hack that I can use to make `endfloat` work for them or can I use something else?

**EDIT**

According to section 8.3 of the [endfloat package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/endfloat) documentation,

> The trick is using the command
>
> `\DeclareDelayedFloat{⟨float⟩}[⟨file extension⟩]{⟨heading⟩}`
>
> which makes the new floating environment known to the endfloat package

but this does not seem to work for `lstlisting` floats.

Comment: I've added the information about `lstlisting` floats to your question, and deleted my answer. A question with no answers is more likely to draw attention from someone who actually knows what they are doing, unlike me.

Comment: Perhaps, it is possible to use the `newfloat` package to wrap `lstlisting` floats in order to make them float to the end in conjunction with `endfloat`? (See http://www.ctan.org/pkg/newfloat)

Comment: @IanThompson: What did you say in your answer?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer --- basically just what's in the question after 'EDIT'.

Comment: @IanThompson: Well, that was indeed a very helpful edit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think, I have found a possible solution

First some explanation:

> \DeclareDelayedFloat{⟨float⟩}[⟨file extension⟩]{⟨heading⟩}

This command from `endfloat` package prepares the package for floating environments other than standard `figure` or `table`, say for example

```
\DeclareDelayedFloat{exercise}{fexe}{List of Exercises}
```

It requires (see lines 350 and following of `endfloat.sty`) that there is a `listofexercises` command.

Well, this is the point where

`\DeclaredDelayedFloat{lstlisting}{flol}{List of Listings}`

fails:

**There is no `\listoflstlistings` command ;-)**

It is called `lstlistoflistings` instead. The clue is just to say

`\newcommand\listoflstlistings}{\lstlistoflistings}%`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{blindtext} % Just for dummy content
% use \usepackage[nomarkers]{endfloat} to drop the markers in the text
\usepackage{endfloat}  

%%% \DeclareDelayedFloat looks for the \listoflstlistings command
%%% since it is assumed, that there is an associate command for the list of listings
%%% 'environment' lstlistings as given to \DeclareDelayedFloat ---> listoflstlistings.
%%% However, `listings` uses \lstlistoflistings, so define this new command
%%% to make \DeclareDelayedFloat happy. 
\newcommand{\listoflstlistings}{\lstlistoflistings}%

% Change `List of Listings` as third argument at will.
\DeclareDelayedFloat{lstlisting}[flol]{\textbf{List of Listings}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First content}


\blindtext

\begin{lstlisting}[language=C,float=t,caption={Hello World - a famous example}]
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  printf("Hello World\n");
  return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
\end{lstlisting}

\blindtext

\begin{lstlisting}[language=C++,float=t,caption={Hello World - a famous example, again}]
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
  return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And if you are now confused about `\listof` and `\lstlisting`, `\listoflstlistings` ... I know, what you mean ;-)

File versions:

> Endfloat:
>
> ```
> \def\filename{endfloat}
> \def\fileversion{v2.5d}
> \def\filedate{2011/12/25}
> \def\docdate{2011/12/05}
> ```
>
> Listings:
>
> ```
> \def\filedate{2014/03/04}
> \def\fileversion{1.5c}
> ```

So, `listings` is quite new.

Comment: When I tried this example, I got the error `Runaway argument?
! File ended while scanning use of \efloat@xfloat.`

Comment: @IanThompson: I tried with latex/pdflatex/xelatex/lualatex, all run without errors. I use the latest TeXLive state 'just' before the recent freeze state. I will post the versions of packages.

Comment: I updated my packages, but it still doesn't work. Since it works for you, and for @John, something must be wrong on my machine. No wonder I couldn't solve the problem!

Comment: I have an `old` TeXLive setup on another computer, I can try to compile the code, but the error message has its origin probably from `endfloat` package. Thank you very much for awarding the bounty anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Christians solution is great when relying on the float commands of lstlisting.

But I wanted to use the caption and float package to change all of my floats. Tables, Figures, Listings the whole shebang.

So based on [this](http://spoonfulofhacking.blogspot.de/2009/06/float.html) and Christians brilliant find I came up with the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{blindtext} % Just for dummy content
\usepackage{endfloat}  
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{float}

%%% Declare new float environment for Listings
\newcommand{\listofsnippetname}{List of Listings}
\newlistof{snippet}{lol}{\listofsnippetname}
\newfloat{snippet}{thp}{lol}[chapter]
\floatname{snippet}{Listing}
\newcommand{\snippetautorefname}{Listing}
\renewcommand{\thesnippet}{\thechapter.\arabic{snippet}}

%%% \DeclareDelayedFloat looks for the \listofsnippets command
\newcommand{\listofsnippets}{\listofsnippet}

%%% This makes endfloat aware of the snippet floats
\DeclareDelayedFloat{snippet}[flol]{List of Listings}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First content}

\blindtext

\begin{snippet}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=C]
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  printf("Hello World\n");
    return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
\end{lstlisting}
\caption[Hello World]{The usual example.}
\label{lst:helloworld}
\end{snippet}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You did not ask for floating of figures/tables ... that is already done by `endfloat`, therefore I omitted it in my solution. It addresses the `listings` problem only.

Comment: Wasn't meant as criticism. My question was slightly ambiguous.

Comment: I did not take it as criticism, I was rather confused whether I misinterpreted your question, after I read your answer. Good question, by the way!!!